# C++ Sorting linked list by date

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list

I want to sort my linked list by date:

```
void sortuj(List *head)
{
    List curr = *head;
    List next;
    int temp;

    while (curr && curr->next)
    {

    next = curr->next;
        while (next)
        {
            if (curr->year > next->year)
            {
                std::swap(next->day, curr->day);
                std::swap(next->month, curr->month);
                std::swap(next->year, curr->year);
                std::swap(next->hour, curr->hour);
                std::swap(next->minute, curr->minute);
                std::swap(next->length, curr->length);
                std::swap(next->group, curr->group);
                std::swap(next->description, curr->description);
            }
            next = next->next;
        }
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}
```

It's working now, but just for a year and I have a few more parameters to sort by. I want to sort from oldest to newest, I read all data from file. How can I do it?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: I got data in file in this form
20 12 2017 14 28 20
Bussiness meeting
Something something

I load it to the program, create linked list and now i need to sort nodes by date

Comment: `std::tie(curr->year, curr->month, curr->day) > std::tie(next->year, next->month, next->day)` or create  your own compare function.

Comment: You can do it by modifying your compare function. The only thing that's different is how you determine the relative ordering of the elements in your list. Right now, you're just comparing the years. Just change the comparison logic to whatever criteria you wish, with everything else remaining the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++11 (or later) an easy way is to use `std::tie` from `<tuple>`.

Example use in your code (just guessing here):

```
if (std::tie(curr->year, curr->month, curr->day)
  > std::tie(next->year, next->month, next->day)) {
...
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's working. But how can I do it without that?

Comment: @konpociagowy *why?* If you have special requirements and/or limitations, you should write them in your question, not dismiss valid answers without explanation as to what's off.

Comment: To compare to structures in a proper way you can unravel it as follow: (here simplifying) `ìf(cy > ny || (cy == ny && cm > nm) || (cm == nm && cd > nd)`

Answer (score 0):

In your function you just compare the year, if there are data with same years, your function can't sort them.

You can convert D-M-Y time to `time_t`, like:

```
#include <time.h>
...
time_t convertTime(List& l)
{
    /*struct*/ tm _tm;
    _tm.tm_year = l.year;
    _tm.tm_mon = l.month;
    _tm.tm_mday = l.day;
    _tm.tm_hour = l.hour;
    _tm.tm_min = l.minute;
    _tm.tm_sec = l.second;
    _tm.tm_isdst = 0;
    return mktime(&_tm);
}
```

`time_t` refers to the seconds of time in parameters to 1970.

Comment: I tried to figure it out but it constantly returns me -1. How I'm supposed to call a function?